# Sending GraphQl query with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, facebook-graph-api, resttemplate

I am new in graph api. I have to get some fields from facebook graph api with RestTemplate. Unfortunately, I tried a lot, searched a lot, but can't find any solution

my code:

```
String pageAccessToken = pageAccessToken();
String url = GRAPH_API_BASE_URL + "/"+ getPageId() +"?fields=ratings{review_text,reviewer{id,name,picture},created_time,recommendation_type}&access_token={pageAccessToken}";

restTemplate.getForObject(url, Review.class, pageAccessToken);
```

it gives me this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'pageAccessToken'

this query works in facebook graph api tool for developers

I have searched for sending graph query with RestTemplate, but I can't find any information which helps me for resolving this problem

I think that I made a mistake when sending this query. please provide me some samples about sending complicated graph query with RestTemplate for understanding this method

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I have solved this problem by using https://restfb.com/ library instead of RestTemplate

code sample :

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(pageAccessToken(), Version.LATEST);

    Connection<OpenGraphRating> ogRatingConn =
            facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/ratings",
                    OpenGraphRating.class,
                    Parameter.with("fields", "reviewer{id,name,picture},review_text,created_time,recommendation_type"));
```